# Bootstrap 4 - 3 column layout, in lg pull up right column right under left column

Tags: bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4, 3 column layout

Problem: In lg view-port, the right column appears after the end of the main column content, how could it be "pulled up" so that it appears right under the left column?

Problem demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/2kqug64j/4/
https://fiddle.jshell.net/2kqug64j/4/show/

Code (also available in jsfiddle):

```
<div class="container-fluid body-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 order-lg-first">
      <p>Left column - right should be right under this content in lg view - instead of after the end of the Main column content end</p>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-6 order-first">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <p>
          Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, and some more text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 order-last">
      <p>
      Right column...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To visualise what I'm trying to achieve, right column should be *right under* the content of the left column and not at the level where main column text ends (if the text of the main column was 10x longer then the right column content would begin way down the page:
[image]

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue on Chrome 62. Looks to be perfectly under left column at large viewport, left-main-right order at xl, and all three are separate at smaller viewport.

Comment: @101arrowz I've updated the question with a screenshot to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I've offered a solution for your problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You should add CSS to set height to 0 at large. This WILL cause issues with any styling like border. I think there are better solutions, however.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) {
  #main {
    height: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid body-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 order-lg-first">
      <p>Left column - right should be right under this content in lg view - instead of after the end of the Main column content end</p>
    </div>
    <div id="main" class="col-12 col-lg-8 col-xl-6 order-first">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="main">
          <p>
          Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, Main column, and some more text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 order-last">
      <p>
      Right column...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/0pv8jmqb/)

Comment: Thank you @101arrowz - I've tested this and unfortunately it does create a number of issues including overflow over footer etc.